# How to change table name of from clause in PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc

Hi i have a small problem, how do i switch tables to get results from??
The code below is not working.However that should give you some idea of what i am trying to do.
Thanks for the help

```
String typelogin=null;
if(xx){
   typelogin="users_table";
}else{
   typelogin="admin_table";
}
String sqlStr = "Select * from "+typelogin+" where username=? and userpassword=?";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStr);
```

The full code:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sqlStr = "Select * from "+typelogin+" where username=? and userpassword=?";


            PreparedStatement pstmt=conn.prepareStatement(sqlStr);
            pstmt.setString(1,user);
            pstmt.setString(2,password);
            //step 6 Process result
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

The error i am getting:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fromspmovy_admin where username='abc' and userpassword='abc'' at line 1
```

Answer[SOLVED]:

forgot to put white space

```
from " + typelogin + " where
```

Comment: From your error message: `'fromspmovy_admin where ...` looks like you missed a whitespace between `from` and your table name. Make sure you're doing this in the right way in all your methods.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza well, this is what was wrong thank you so much, please answer the exact thing here so i can chose this as answer, thanks alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your error message: `'fromspmovy_admin where ...` looks like you missed a whitespace between `from` and your table name. Make sure you're doing this in the right way in all your methods (note that in your current example this won't happen).

Answer (score 0):

If you will use ? for pass the variables, you must use PreparedStatement not Statement. Also according your error message you need to add a white space after from (check fromspmovy_admin)

Comment: I am using prepared statement ok i made an edit for the full code i am using pls have a look. thanks